# Getting an image to show up in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, javax.imageio

I am trying to display a background image in a JFrame, but the image isn't showing up and I can't find what the error in the code is.

```
public class GraphicsComponent extends JComponent
{
    int xPosition = 200;//initializes and declares the x coordinate
    int yPosition = 400;//initializes and declares the y coordinate
    Image i;

public GraphicsComponent()
{
    try{
        File sky = new File("lib/background.png");
        i = ImageIO.read(sky);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //overrides paintComponent method in JComponent
{
    if (i == null) return;
    g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Comment: whats in your main program..

Comment: Can you post the complete code. How are you adding it into `JFrame`?

Comment: Where is the image located? Is it located within the src/application context or relative to the execution of the program? Is an exception thrown? You should also be calling super.paintComponent, especially for JComponent as it's transparent by default

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you creating a custom component? If you create a custom component then you also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the component to return the size of the image so the layout manager can paint the component at its proper size.

So the size of the component is probably zero, so there is nothing to paint.

The easiest solution is to just use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon` and let the layout manager deal with the size issue.

Comment: Everyone do in the same why Don't know why:)

Comment: I tried using that but for some reason it still isn't being displayed:           JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("background.png")); 
        frame.add(iconLabel);

Comment: @user2963365, post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates how you use the JLabel. Make sure you add the label to the frame BEFORE you make the frame visible.